# Is it possible to have floated divs of variable sizes 'wrap'/stick/flow to each other?

Tags: css, css-float

I'm trying to align a list of div blocks by 2 columns that have varying heights by floating them to each other. If every block's size is fix, they will naturally stack with one another neatly, however because this one involves varying heights, for blocks that are taller, the adjacent block will have alot of blank space below, before going on with the next block.

However, I noticed that this only happens to one side, if the blocks are floated left, then the right columns blocks will automatically fill up any blank spaces, and vice versa.

However I am now trying to seek a solution for achieving the fluidity for both sides.

You can see an example of what I mean [here](http://test.fred-lin.com/test.html).

Everything on the 2nd column is nicely fitted, but on the left side, there is a lot of blank spaces for taller sizes.

CSS is like this:

```
.container {
    width: 600px;
}
.item {
    width: 250px;
    height:  auto;
    background: darkgray;
    border: 1px solid black;
    float: left;
    margin: 5px 0 0 5px;
    padding: 5px;
}
```

Comment: You should close this question and ask it on http://doctype.com instead.

Comment: oh I'm sorry. a google search on the topic led to a related post here. But you're right, doctype.com seems to be the more relevant place to ask. Thanks!

Comment: No problem. doctype just recently join the League of Justice and up until they joined, this would have been the place to ask.

Answer (score 1):

You have 3 options all which have it's drawbacks.

1. Write a JavaScript solution that
   will calculate each items starting
   position and then reposition each
   one accordingly using relative
   positioning.
2. Change your markup so that there are
   two container columns that are
   opposing floats. You'll have to
   distribute the items between the two
   programmatically.
3. Use a table so that each item's
   height matches the one next to it.

Obviously the last two aren't very semantically sound and the first one could be impractical depending on how large the list of items could become. I believe there is a way to do it in CSS 3 but it lacks browser support at the moment.

Comment: +1 - Depending on your content you can find ways to divide the blocks into two semantic categories, making #2 a fairly semantic option. There are also ways to work the design around that issue so the space is less noticeable (not putting backgrounds on the boxes for example).